# How to trigger the Span element to populate with the value entered in Input field (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm creating a Bookmarklet for a webpage and have come across a Span id="totalAmount" element (summary table) that normally populates after a value is manually entered into an Input field (id="Amount") by clicking into it and typing the value. I can successfully enter the value using the Bookmarklet but the Span id="totalAmount" element is not being populated. What am i missing?

This is the HTML

```
<input id="Amount" class="with-prefix sum-amount" type="tel" value="" name="Amount" data-val-required="Please enter your amount" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$" data-val-regex="Please enter the amount" data-val-reasonableincome="" data-val-number="The field What is your amount? must be a number." data-val="true" aria-describedby="AmountTooltip"/>

<div class="summary-table clearfix">
<div class="summary-table-item">
<span class="text">Total amount</span>
<span class="curr-sign">£</span>
<span id="totalAmount" class="value"/>
</div>
```

When entering value into Input field manually, the span element gets the same value populated and the code changes to:

```
<span id="totalAmount" class="value">25000.00</span>
```

But when I use following Bookmarklet, although the Input field is successfully entered with a value, the "totalAmount" Span isn't getting populated

```
javascript: var newPage = {
    formFill: function() {
        document.querySelectorAll("#Amount")[0].value = '25000';
    }
};
newPage.formFill()
```

**NOTE**: I'm unable to modify the HTML due to permissions

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`span` is not the `input` element, it has `innerHTML`, not `value`

```
document.getElementById( "Amount" ).onchange = function(){
   document.getElementById("totalAmount").innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, i can enter the value into the Input field...but i'm expecting the span to populate once the value has been entered.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. Nothing was entered on the Input field

Comment: I am little confused. You want to populate span from input or input from span?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When a numeric value is entered into the Input field, the Span should be populated with that same value. This is the behaviour seen on the webpage when this is done manually. I.e. a user clicks into input field, types value, clicks away or onto next field and then the Span is populated. This is not happening when the value is entered using the Bookmarklet

Comment: To clarify further, it's the span id="totalAmount" field that isn't being populated. I've updated the original post

Comment: @Enzo try the updated code now. I had made a simple mistake there.

Comment: This code should work unless your question is missing some key information. Can you try and share a fiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the span is not closed properly. Please correct that.

The query is happening on Input element and not span.

And if you want the span to populate the value entered in the input element. You have to write a function that does the calculation. This can be bound to a keyboard event.

Comment: I should have mentioned I don't have any control over the html. It's a working website though so I doubt there are any HTML 'fixes' necessary.

Comment: HTML will work even though there are errors in HTML syntax. But to answer the question of how span populates the input value, you should write a event handler to do that. Can be done on blur of input tag

Comment: The Span tag is self closing until a value is entered then it populates with a value and properly closes. I'd like to try the event handler route...can you kindly provide an example of one to solve the above thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// use this code and close span tag.

javascript: var newPage = {
  formFill: function() {
     document.querySelectorAll("#Amount")[0].value  = '25000';
     document.getElementsByClassName(".curr-sign").textContent = '25000';
     document.getElementById("totalAmount").textContent = "25000";
  }
};
newPage.formFill();
```

Comment: This forcefully enters the value 25000 into the totalAmount element. I need it to somehow populate automatically when the value in entered into the input field. Also, i'm not trying to change the curr-sign value to 25000